# General error: 1364 Field 'remember_token' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel-4

I m new to laravel. I wanted to insert the admin credentials into database.

```
public function verify() {
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    if (!Admin::count()) {
        $user = new Admin;
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->password = $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login');
    } else {

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password))) {
            echo("i m in if");
            if (Session::has('pre_admin_login_url')) {
                $url = Session::get('pre_admin_login_url');
                Session::forget('pre_admin_login_url');
                return Redirect::to($url);
            } else {
                $admin = Admin::where('username', 'like', '%' . $username . '%')->first();
                Session::put('admin_id', $admin->id);
                return Redirect::to('/admin/report')->with('notify', 'installation Notification');
            }
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/login?error=1');
        }
    }
```

Admin Model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;

use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

I have changed the database to default value to 'null' but still it gives the same error.This was the application built by code-canyon i haven't know about the querying parameter in which files are they exists.

> Result:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'remember_token'
>   doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `admin` (`username`,
>   `password`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`)values(admin@taxinow.com,y$csyEcrhERoQEszmxNmiOG.bcAZtwC8xeGiF2xyKTd2YLhEbjixm.m,2017-09-21
>   08:34:24, 2017-09-21 08:34:24))

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add a default value for field `remember_token` in your `admin` table

Comment: I have this field in my database but the problem is that i m just passing username and password from the form and i dont know in which file the querying exists.

Comment: yeah i know field is there, but add a default value for your filed in the table, not from the code from the phpmyadmin

Comment: i have added the null value but the error still exists.

Comment: can you show me your table structure

Comment: `admin` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;

Comment: Just try with `'strict' = false` under Mysql in the file : `config/database.php`. However, it is not a valid solution it's a kind of a patch.

Comment: @ketan solanki I have done that as well in config/database.php in connection part but that still not solve the error. I have been working for 5 hours but no luck yet.

Answer (score 4):

i solved this issue on my application, and i want you to try the same.. 
go to your users table and edit the remember_token field, update the default column to NULL.

[image]
once this is done, try running the application again, it should work this time. But if you were using migrations to update your database schema(fields/properties), you could rollback and make this adjustment to that column by adding this nullable() to the remember_token string...

```
$table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
```

i hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin model and add it to the `$protected` fillable as an array

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_name','remember_token',
];
```

Comment: This won't help as it's a MySQL error. Instead of this, make the column nullable.